# USB voltage amplifier

Tags: usb, amplifier

Can I amplify the voltage of a USB supply?
 I mean can I increase the voltage from 5V for example to 7V.

Comment: look up [Boost Converter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter).

Comment: But note that you'll be limited by the current the USB port can provide, even more so with the use of a boost converter, as its output current is less than that on its input.

Comment: so if i use boost converter in my circiut that is powered with usb can i supply moree leds or the same as my current is less

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "amplify" a DC voltage, using for instance an op-amp. But that requires the op-amp to already have a higher supply voltage than the one you want to make.

Probably what you want is to *convert* 5V to 7V.

Converting DC to a higher DC voltage requires first turning the DC into AC, storing the energy in a capacitor or inductor, then rectifying and filtering ripple to end up with DC again. Keywords to search: `smps`, `dc-dc converter`, `boost converter`, `buck-boost converter`, or `charge pump`.

If conversion was 100% efficient (which it isn't) you'd still be limited to power in = power out, so the answer to "can I power more LEDs" is generally no. It might be more convenient to power some things (like LEDs) from certain voltages, but ultimately they require power.

Comment: In addition to this excellent answer I'd add that designing a USB boost converter is not trivial.  Special care may be needed to limit inrush current, reduce capacitance in reference designs and ensure that ripple noise does not get back to the host.  I spent a long time debugging a circuit where I had blindly copied a reference design and powered it from USB.